# What is the meaning of overloaded 'operator+=' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)

Tags: c++

Today when I was doing leetcode 406, I met with a problem about operator overload. Specifically, I want to move the iterator to a certain position. I want to use operator += to achieve that. But when I finish the overload operator code, compiler shows an error:

```
overloaded 'operator+=' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)
    std::list<vector<int>>::iterator operator += (list<vector<int>>& it, int a) {
```

I don't know the meaning of that.
Here is the code:

```
struct myclass {
    bool operator() (vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b) {
        if(a[0] == b[0]) return a[1] < b[1]; // if the height is same, the one with smaller k is prior!
        return (a[0] > b[0]);
    }
} compare;

class Solution {
public:  
    std::list<vector<int>>::iterator operator += (list<vector<int>>& it, int a) {
        while(a-- > 0) {
            it++;
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int>> reconstructQueue(vector<vector<int>>& people) {
        sort(people.begin(), people.end(), compare);
        list<vector<int>> que;
        for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
            int pos = people[i][1];
            std::list<vector<int>>::iterator it = que.begin();
            it += pos;
            que.insert(it, people[i]);
        }
        return vector<vector<int>>(que.begin(), que.end());
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to remove the first **explicit** parameter `list<vector<int>>& it`. This is because `operator+=` is a member function and so already has an **implicit** `this` parameter which makes the total number of parameters to be 3.

Comment: There is already a function doing that: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

Comment: Operators have a very specific meaning. You shouldn't overload them for general purpose. Write a specific named function instead (or use an existing one, like mch says).

Comment: @AnoopRana specifically a non-static member function. Not that `operator+=` _can_ be static. Removing the first parameter will not fix the problem though.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes it is a non-static member function. Removing the first parameter will get rid of the error: *overloaded 'operator+=' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)* though. That's all i am saying. Agreed that it will not solve the problem.

Comment: I understand your meaning, mch. But if I just want to overload the operator +=, what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You were probably trying to "fix" the compiler error in the line

```cpp
it += pos;
```

`operator+=` has to have a specific syntax [according to the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#18).
If implemented as non-static member function, it will always have a hidden (except for C++23 deduced this) first parameter pointing to the class instantiation (`*this` of type `Solution` in your case).

The issue is caused by the container type you chose: `std::list` has a (legacy) bidirectional iterator. That means you can only increase (e.g. `++it`) or decrease (e.g. `--it`) it. If you'd would have used e.g. `std::vector`, there would be a (legacy) random access iterator, and `operator +=` would already be defined.

It's often not a good idea to implement arithmetic operators for standard library types: they were not implemented in the first place for a reason.

Like mch said in the comments, the standard library has a function to increase the iterator a specific number of times: [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance). I.e., the line can be replaced with

```cpp
std::advance(it,pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do operator overloading as a non-static member function of a class, it is assumed that the first operand is the object through with the function is being called(non-static member functions are always called through an object), in other words, `*this`.

So to avoid that, in your case(because you don't have access to the definition of the class `list::iterator`), define the `operator+=` in a static context(outside the Solution class).

Another way would be to create a subclass to inherit the `std::iterator` and then make some adjustments to the code. There you can directly overload the `operator+=`. But that would just be overkill.

Also why are you passing a list as the first argument? Shouldn't it be an iterator? I am assuming that is a typo.